# How to launch a notification after reading data from remote database?

Tags: android, web-services, notifications

I develop an android application and I need to launch a notification after reading some data from my remote database.

I invoke a web service in background and after I get the data it must be making some tests finally, I launch my notification.

In each 2 minutes I check if new updates is available in my database, if it is the case, I must launch a notification.

There is what I do actually in my background service:

```
public class CoursesNotifications extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

final static String ACTION = "new course arriving";
final static String STOP_SERVICE_BROADCAST_KEY = "StopServiceBroadcastKey";
final static int RQS_STOP_SERVICE = 1;
//message items
final static String SERVER_URL = "localhost:8080/messages";
final static String TAG_idmessage = "idmessage";
final static String TAG_idtaxi = "idtaxi";
final static String TAG_messageaccept = "messageaccept";
final static String TAG_textmessage = "textmessage";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ticketList;
private static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
CoursesNotifications coursesnotificationservce;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    coursesnotificationservce = new CoursesNotifications();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      new MessageCourse().execute();
    Log.d(ACTION,"");

      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    //  this.unregisterReceiver(coursesnotificationservce);
    super.onDestroy();
    // I want to restart this service again in one hour
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(
            alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60),
            PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, CoursesNotifications.class), 0)
    );
}

private class MessageCourse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (ticketList != null) {

           setNormalNotification();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(SERVER_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray messages = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject messageobjet = messages.getJSONObject(i);
                    String idmessage = messageobjet.getString(TAG_idmessage);
                    String idtaxi = messageobjet.getString(TAG_idtaxi);
                    boolean messageaccept = messageobjet.getBoolean(TAG_messageaccept);
                    String textmessage = messageobjet.getString(TAG_textmessage);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> message = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    message.put(TAG_idmessage, idmessage);
                    message.put(TAG_idtaxi, idtaxi);
                    message.put(TAG_messageaccept, String.valueOf(messageaccept));
                    message.put(TAG_messageaccept, textmessage);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    ticketList.add(message);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (ticketList != null) {
            setNormalNotification();
        }}


    private Notification setNormalNotification() {
        Bitmap remote_picture = null;



        // Setup an explicit intent for an ResultActivity to receive.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RepondreCourse.class);

        // TaskStackBuilder ensures that the back button follows the recommended convention for the back key.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself).
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(RepondreCourse.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.taxi)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
               // .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.profile, "One", resultPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.document, "Two", resultPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.message, "Three", resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("Normal Notification")
                .setContentText("This is an example of a Normal Style.").build();
    }
```

And this is my BraodcastReceiver:

```
public class CourseNotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, CoursesNotifications.class));

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context, CourseNotificationalarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gpsTrackerIntent, 0);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.taxi.binov.taxidriver.Services.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int intervalInMinutes = sharedPreferences.getInt("intervalInMinutes", 1);
        Boolean currentlyTracking = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("currentlyTracking", false);

       // if (currentlyTracking) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), intervalInMinutes * 60000*5, pendingIntent); // 3*60000 = 3 minute,

        }
```

and finally there is my last class to acheive this task:

```
public class CourseNotificationalarmReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, CoursesNotifications.class)); }
```

But the notification don't show when I run the application

Really I hope your help

Comment: Thanks for sharing requirement. Can you please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nope your explanation is not clear! Be more specific about the issues and share more details, your try, your searching, etc.!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is what i want to do : in each 2 minutes I check if new updates is available in my database, if it is the case, i must launch a notification. This application is designed for a taxi driver: if there is a new race the taxi driver must be notified;

Comment: Updated question with the comment details!

Comment: Still let us know what have you tried so far? Sharing requirement on Stackoverflow doesn't work, you have to search and try to implement yourself first! If you would face any issue then share it here!

Comment: Hello Paresh, I add more details about my question. I need your help

Comment: Please There is any one who can help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Did you checked my answer and is your issue resolved?

Comment: Thank Paresh for your reply... Yes, I check your answer but it's the same problem!!. Please, verify my code if i do my task with the best requirements.

Comment: Sorry that's not possible! I have suggested what I found lacking in your code!

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `notify()` method and that's the reason notification isn't getting shown!

```
int notifyId = 1;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(notifyId, mBuilder.build());
```